# my PDO update query is inserting undefined value in only one column , why?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

i have four fields of record in my table

1. name
2. email
3. phone
4. address

i am using PDO method for updating record in php with ajax, when i call insert query it works fine but when i update my record it updates only three starting fields  , in address field they inserted *undefined* text value , where i am doing mistake ?

screenshot of my front end
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-PfnAjLGR2xendqM2NsaUVuLW8

### # My html code #

```
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>">

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nm">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm-<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" value= "<?php echo $row['name'];  ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="em">Email</label>
                        <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="em-<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" value= "<?php echo $row['email'];  ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ph">Phone</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ph-<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" value= "<?php echo $row['phone'];  ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ad">Address</label>
                        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="ph-<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" > <?php echo $row['address'];?> </textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="updateData(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

### my ajax script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateData(str){
           var id = str;
           var name = $('#nm-'+str).val();
           var email = $('#em-'+str).val();
           var phone = $('#ph-'+str).val();
           var address = $('#ad-'+str).val();
           $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "server.php?p=edit" ,
            data : "nm="+name+"&em="+email+"&ph="+phone+"&ad="+address+"&id="+id,
            success :function(data){
              viewData();
            }
           });
          }
   </script>
```

### PDO file code

```
else if($page=='edit'){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
     $name = $_POST['nm'];
     $email = $_POST['em'];
     $phone = $_POST['ph'];
     $address = $_POST['ad'];

     $stmt = $db->prepare(" update crud set name=? , email=? , phone=? , address=? where id=?");  
     $stmt->bindValue(1,$name);
     $stmt->bindValue(2,$email);
     $stmt->bindValue(3,$phone);
     $stmt->bindValue(4,$address);
     $stmt->bindValue(5,$id);
     if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "succesfully updated";
     }
     else{
        echo "failed updated data";
     }
}
```

Comment: maybe because you have the wrong #id in address here: `<textarea ... id="ph-<?php...`

Comment: so it's a simple "typo" that you could have found yourself with simple debugging. Next time check where you've got what values...

Comment: no sir id attribute is right , i need to pick id thats why i am using this query inside id attribute , this method works fine under above three labels

Comment: No, Sir. address is undefined, because there is no element with the id 'ad-'+x. So will be $_POST['ad'] the string 'undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a simple typo here:

```
   <label for="ad">Address</label>
                                          <!-- here: -->
   <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="ph-<?php echo $row['id'];  ?>" > <?php echo $row['address'];?> 
   </textarea>
```

It should be

```
   ... id="ad-...
```

because you're referring to it in js like that:

```
   var address = $('#ad-'+str).val();
```

Since there is no html element with an id 'ad-'+x,  `address` will be `undefined` -> `$_POST['ad']` will contain the string 'undefined'.

Comment: I'm happy to get an explanation for the downvote!

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted Jeff, sure wasn't mine and this answer to me looks correct.